# Hibernate result list cast to get rows

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Hello I had problem with iterate Hibernate ResultList

I had followed query that I got from external class:

```
queryContent = "select distinct c.identity, c.number, c.status, ctr.name, aab.paymentConditions.currency       from AgreementStateBean ast       join ast.currentAgreement aab       join conagr.contract c  where c.agreementStateId = ?   and con.mainContractor = true ? "
```

And I must sum whole aab.paymentConditions.currency, check numbers of statutes and names.

I want to do this by iterate list of results:

```
    Query q = session.createQuery(queryContent); 
    List result = q.list();
    Long wholeCurrency, numberOfStatutes;

    for(Object res : result){
        //wholeCurrency += res.getColumnName?
    }
```

My question is how to cast res Object to have possibility to get concrete column values? I had read about create map inside hibernate query but I don't know it is good practice to modyfied query string by adding

```
   "new map(" prefix and then ")"
```

before from sql statement

Solution:

After All I decided to use map in my query. I modified my external query by adding hibernate map statement by replacing select by 'select new map(' and from by ') from'.
Additional thing is to add 'as' statement with name of key because without them column keys are integer.
So after all my query looks like follow:

```
"select new map( distinct c.identity, c.number, c.status as status, ctr.name as name, aab.paymentConditions.currency as currency  )    from AgreementStateBean ast       join ast.currentAgreement aab       join conagr.contract c  where c.agreementStateId = ?   and con.mainContractor = true ? "
```

That was the most siutable solution for me, I tried with 'NEW com.example.MyClass' as Kostja suggested but in my case I didn't have control for incoming query so I can not rely on pernament constructor.

```
new List( select...
```

Is also interest but it also didn't tell me on with position I have my field that give me information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to have a typed representation of your result without it being an entity itself. For this, you can use constructor queries:

```
"SELECT NEW com.example.MyClass( e.name, e.data) FROM Entity e"
```

`MyClass` has to have a matching constructor. Full qualification (`com.example`) is not mandatory AFAIK.

If you are using this query often, creating a view in the DB may be a good idea. You can map a view to an entity just as if it were a regular table, but please note that you cannot store changes to you data over a mapped view.

EDIT: Turns out, [mapping to an unspecified Map is alright with Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#ql-select-clause):

`select new map( mother as mother, offspr as offspr, mate as mate )`

Comment: So If I'm afraid about that query can be modified only way is to use "SELECT NEW MAP( e.name, e.data) FROM ..." and then use names of columns?

Comment: Using projection queries prevents - mapped to classes or not prevents you from making changes to the db directly. In order to store changes you will need to either map the properties back to entities (which can negate the benefits from using projection queries) or use bulk updates.

Comment: @MazerytFreager - in Java, you cannot use `new Map` as Map is an interface. You must use a class that has a constructor that accepts all the selected attributes, which can use a map internally.

Comment: tkanks that help me a lot

Comment: @MazerytFreager - please excuse my ignorance. Turns out that hibernate actually supports the `new map` syntax - see user3739160's answer

Answer (score 1):

As per http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#ql-select-clause
you can use

```
queryContent = "select new list(distinct c.identity, c.number, c.status, ctr.name, aab.paymentConditions.currency)       from AgreementStateBean ast       join ast.currentAgreement aab       join conagr.contract c  where c.agreementStateId = ?   and con.mainContractor = true ? "
```

And you get `List<List>` as result.

Comment: +1 Cool, mapping to a Map is possible after all - you live and learn ;)